# is method overloading is possible in this case

Tags: overloading

I assume that is function overloading since it has diff type of parameter .My question is

Two functions, which has diff type of parameter, diff return type will be considered as Function Overloading?

```
public class Header {

public int addTwoNumbers(int a, int b){

return a+b;

}

public double addTwoNumbers(double a, double b){

return a+b;

}
```

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: Looks like Java to me.

Answer (score 0):

Independently of the programming language, a method overload occurs when two or more methods have the same identifier while their parameters are different either in number, order and type.

For example:

```
// This is also overloading
public void x(int a, double b) { }
public void x(double a, int b) { }
```

In your case, `addTwoNumbers` is overloaded because two methods share the same identifier while their parameters have different types.

Answer (score 0):

You can also test it in visual studio itself. 
If visual studio is not giving any error while declaring these functions and when you make a call to this function then visual studio auto intelligence is showing two overloads of this function that means function overloading is done.